# CSS vertical line for complex tbody

Tags: html, css, html-table, pseudo-element

I've a dynamic HTML page which has a table with multiple 'tbody' elements.
Each tbody element is a little complex as it has a nested structure.

I need to have a vertical line inside each of the tbody.
For that matter, I tried to use pseudo-element 'after' to create the vertical line. But it doesn't seem to work.

Could you please help me fix it?

Here's the sample design:

[image: Sample UI Design]

My code:

```css
.container tr:last-child::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  right: 10px;    
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="container">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h3>Heading 1</h3>
        <div>Content</div>
      </th>
      <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="container">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h3>Heading 2</h3>
        <div>Content</div>
      </th>
      <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="container">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h3>Heading 1</h3>
        <div>Content</div>
      </th>
      <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your table structure..in the `thead`